# WPF binding a background color does not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I work on Appointments system, I have a Listbox that contain DataTemplate has a toggle button represent each appointment, If the appointment confirmed the background color should change, This is my ListBox :

```
<ListBox>                       
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource AppointmentStatusColor}, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="370">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AppointmentID}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Patient.FullName}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToggleButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

The Background property is binding to IValueConverter:

```
public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Brush _appointmentStatusBrush = null;
        var fc = new BrushConverter();
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        Appointment _appointment = (Appointment)value;
        switch (_appointment.Status)
        {
            case 0:
                _appointmentStatusBrush = (Brush)fc.ConvertFrom("#FFFBF7CC");
                break;
            case 1:
                _appointmentStatusBrush = (Brush)fc.ConvertFrom("#FFFFFFFF");
                break;
        }
        return _appointmentStatusBrush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

The binding works when adding a new appointment, but when I update the existing appointment status and refresh the list, the color does not updated !!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented?

Answer (score -1):

`Background` property should be binded to `Appointment.Status` property with `Mode=TwoWay`.

Then, when `Status` changes, `Converter` will be invoked.

So, your binding should look like : `Background="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource AppointmentStatusColor}, NotifyOnValidationError=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Comment: The control does not change the background, so that should not matter.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan, Thanks for your answer, But how can the Converter invoked if I does not bind it !!!!

Comment: @AbdulsalamElsharif You have used the `Converter` in your `Binding` in `DataTemplate`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Status should Notify of its changes. Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged ?